# Using Amazon's WSDL web service from F# 3.0 with type providers

Tags: f#, wsdl, type-providers

I wrote the following F# 3.0 program using the built-in WSDL type provider to autogenerate an F# version of the Amazon WSDL:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type azn = WsdlService<"http://soap.amazon.com/schemas2/AmazonWebServices.wsdl">

let authorRequest author =
    azn.ServiceTypes.AuthorRequest(author=author)

do
    let client = azn.GetAmazonSearchPort()
    let response = client.AuthorSearchRequest(authorRequest "Harrop")
    printfn "%s" response.TotalResults
```

When I run this I get a exciting internal exception from the Microsoft toolstack at run time:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (410) Gone. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Program.azn.ServiceTypes.AmazonSearchPort.AuthorSearchRequest(AuthorRequest AuthorSearchRequest1)
   at Program.azn.ServiceTypes.AmazonSearchPortClient.AuthorSearchRequest(AuthorRequest AuthorSearchRequest1)
   at Program.azn.ServiceTypes.SimpleDataContextTypes.AmazonSearchPortClient.AuthorSearchRequest(AuthorRequest )
   at <StartupCode$ConsoleApplication2>.$Program.main@() in c:\users\jon\documents\visual studio 11\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.fs:line 5
```

I've since found out that there is a more recent schema here:

```
type azn = WsdlService<"http://soap.amazon.com/schemas2/AmazonWebServices.wsdl">
```

But this doesn't fix my exciting error message. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the end-to-end solution but can probably help you to move a bit further

Url that you are using right now corresponds to the stale version of API, I believe more recent one is http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

If you just pass this url to WsdlService type provider, everything will be fine in in design time, but in runtime with weird error like "*There was an error in serializing body of message ItemSearchRequest1: 'Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1). error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Program.Amazon.ServiceTypes.ImageSet[]' to 'Program.Amazon.ServiceTypes.ImageSet'; error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Program.Amazon.ServiceTypes.ImageSet' to 'Program.Amazon.ServiceTypes.ImageSet[]'*".

It seems to be the known error ([here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=72429)), to fix it you should set ForceUpdate=false, and LocalSchemaFile='your local schema file' and then fix the definition of ImagesSet in your local schema file from

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ImageSets">
```

to

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ImageSets">

type Amazon = Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.WsdlService<
                @"http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl", 
                ForceUpdate=false, 
                LocalSchemaFile="amazon.wsdlschema"
                >

let searchAuthor author = 
    Amazon.ServiceTypes.ItemSearch(Request = [| Amazon.ServiceTypes.ItemSearchRequest(Author = author) |])

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let amazon = Amazon.GetAWSECommerceServicePort()
    let result = amazon.ItemSearch (searchAuthor "Harrop")
    0
```

However this is still not the end of the story - this code throws MessageSecurityException: "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'". It looks like the known issue as well (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278158/amazon-api-authentication-error)), but to check the solution you'll need Amazon user id and secret key (I don't have ones).